# Skinnable Controls (WPF/UWP)

Tags: wpf, controls, uwp, skinning

I'm building a virtual instrument. The controls have to look nice, and they have to look like other virtual instruments. Here's an example of what they need to look like:

http://www.vstskins.com/

Basically, knobs, faders, switches, etc. etc.

The standard Telerik, Infragistics controls etc. etc. just don't fit the bill for this. I need the controls to accept a bitmap image to be laid over the top - not designed with Xaml styling. I'm talking about actual skins as opposed to a theme.

Are there any controls out there that I can use?

PS: At this point I'm not sure if I will go with WPF, or UWP, but access to good controls will have a big impact on my platform decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I commissioned someone to build the controls I needed. They work well:

https://bitbucket.org/MelbourneDeveloper/vst-controls-.net

There is a switch, knob, and fader, and all are skinnable with raster images.

This is not an open source library but all are welcome to use the controls for personal projects that are not commercial in nature.

Answer (score 0):

First, as about WPF vs UWP, the decision should be based on your expectation for the usage scenario of your application: Do you want to publish your application to windows store? Do you need to work across various multiple devices? Or you just want to develop a desktop application? UWP and WPF both have rich UI element library. You can choose based on your own concern. UI wise you can technically do the same thing.

Here I focus on solutions in UWP. My understanding for your requirement is that you need to change control's background to different images in code behind. Please correct me if I misunderstood. There are various way to set image source: Using a relative URI, Using files from a network or local storage, Using a stream source, etc. Please refer to [MSDN online help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image.source.aspx). Below is a very simple sample:

```
In XAML:

<StackPanel>
    <Ellipse  Height="200" Width="300">
        <Ellipse.Fill> 
            <ImageBrush x:Name="test" ImageSource="Assets/image1.jpg"  />
        </Ellipse.Fill>
    </Ellipse>
    <Button Click="Button_Click">Change Background</Button>
</StackPanel>   

In C#:
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   Uri uri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/hero.jpg");
   test.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(uri);
}
```